# Problem using any operator in plpgsql function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

When i run this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_styles(raw_styles text)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
declare
    arr_value TEXT[];
    upper_limit INTEGER;    
    style_ids INTEGER[];
    BEGIN
        arr_value   := string_to_array(raw_styles, ',');
        upper_limit := array_upper(arr_value, 1);

        RAISE NOTICE 'arr_value = %', arr_value;
        SELECT music_style FROM music_style INTO style_ids WHERE name = ANY (arr_value);
        RETURN upper;
    END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

with this query:

```
SELECT insert_styles('Techno,ddd,wer,WJKDF');
```

It gives me the following error:

```
NOTICE:  arr_value = {Techno,ddd,wer,WJKDF}
ERROR:  array value must start with "{" or dimension information
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "insert_styles" line 10 at SQL statement
```

I just can't figure it out. I'am a postgres newbie!

bye!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your `music_style` column has integer datatype you just need to add [`array_agg`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) aggregate into your query:

```
SELECT array_agg(music_style)
FROM music_style
INTO style_ids -- style_ids is integer[]
WHERE name = ANY (arr_value);
```